# Ionic icon dont charge on start

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, icons

When I enter my app, the icons do not load me, but when I do an interaction, they do appear to me. I do not pass any code I do not see necessary. Say that the icons should come out when loading the app after calling a service.

Comment: you really have to provide more details about what icons, you can not see, where you can not see them, what did you try. also read StackOverflow guides on writing a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below command in cmd

```
ionic cordova resources android
```

The above command automatically generate necessary resources(Icon and Splash screen). Check is there any issues related to image dimension in cmd. If it shows as `resources generated` in the end of CMD, then the resources are generated successfully.